# User defined Function to check if Rent has more then 3 games

Tags: sql, sql-server

I how you can help me with the following problem. We want to use Powerbi to get reports but first we want to implement a `constraint` on our database. Because this constraint needs to check another table we want to use a User defined Function.

The function has to check if more then 3 games are being rented. To see if a product(Artikel) is a Game or Console we use the column SPEL_OF_CONSOLE.

How can I see this in a function.

[image]

I Wrote this function:

I wrote this function

```
    (@HUUROVEREENKOMSTNR INT)
    RETURNS BIT --1 or 0
    AS
       BEGIN
       DECLARE @Returnvalue bit =1;
       IF COUNT(*) = 3(
          SELECT v.[Barcode] FROM VERHUURDE_ARTIKELEN v INNER JOIN ARTIKEL A on v.[BARCODE] = A.[BARCODE]
          WHERE @HUUROVEREENKOMSTNR = v.[HUUROVEREENKOMSTNR]
          AND [SPEL_OF_CONSOLE] = 'SPEL'
       )
       SET @Returnvalue = 1;
       ELSE SET @Returnvalue = 0;
       END;
    GO
```

However I get the following Error:

`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.`

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: This part of your query looks wrong: `IF COUNT(*) = 3(`. You probably want to do something like IF (SELECT COUNT(v.[Barcode]) FROM ...) >= 3`. However, as @jarlh commented, the syntax will depend on which system you are using, as the different dialects of SQL are vendor/system specific.

Comment: @jarlh I am using microsoft SQL

Answer (score 0):

I cannot correct your query, it has to many errors, so I will just try to give you some queries that might help you

to get the number of games for a specific huurovereenkomst you could use a query like this

```
declare @VerhuurOvereenKomst int = 123

select count(1)
from   VERHUURDE_ARTIKELEN va
  inner join ARTIKEL a on va.BARCODE = a.BARCODE
                      and a.SPEL_OR_CONSOLE = 'spel'
where va.HUUROVEREENKOMST = @VerhuurOvereenKomst
```

Let's test this theory

first we make some test data

```
DECLARE @va table (HUUROVEREENKOMST int, barcode int)
declare @a table (barcode int, spel_of_console varchar(10))

insert into @va values (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)
insert into @a values (1, 'spel'), (2, 'spel'), (3, 'spel')
```

now we can test the query

```
declare @VerhuurOvereenKomst int = 1

select count(1)
from   @va va
  inner join @a a on va.BARCODE = a.BARCODE
                 and a.SPEL_OF_CONSOLE = 'spel'
where va.HUUROVEREENKOMST = @VerhuurOvereenKomst
```

and yes, the result is `3`

now you want this in a function, that can be done. Look at this example.

```
create function dbo.CheckGameCount(@VerhuurOvereenKomst int) returns bit as
begin
     declare @Result bit

     select @Result = case when count(1) >= 3 then 1 else 0 end
     from   VERHUURDE_ARTIKELEN va
       inner join ARTIKEL a on va.BARCODE = a.BARCODE
                          and a.SPEL_OR_CONSOLE = 'spel'
     where va.HUUROVEREENKOMST = @VerhuurOvereenKomst

    return @Result
end
```

Now you have a query example and a function example that return you result, I don't know in what way you want to build your constraint so I cannot write anything about that.